# How to iterate and show validation errors messages in ejs template?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, connect-flash

I created express app and implemented flash message. Now when i get the flash messages from validation errors I am passing that messages to view. But when i try to get the messages in the view I am not able to see since app showing bunch of error lines. How can i display the error messages in the view based on Ejs view engine.

this is the error messages stored in req.flash('fail_msg')

```
[ { location: 'body',
param: 'email',
value: '',
msg: 'Email must be valid' },
```

{ location: 'body',
    param: 'phone',
    value: '',
    msg: 'Phone Number is required' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'password',
    value: '',
    msg: 'Password is required' },
  { location: 'body',
    param: 'agreeTerms',
    value: undefined,
    msg: 'Must agree term and condition' } ]

from My routes.js

```js
function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
    }
    req.flash('fail_msg', result.array());
    res.render('signup', { message: req.flash('fail_msg')});
}
```

And this is from ejs template

```js
<%if('message'){%>
        <% message.foreach(function(errors){ %>
          <%=errors.msg%>
       <% }) %>
<%}%>
```